# If you're swapping c strings, does the memory allocation also swap?

Tags: c++

Suppose we have the following:

```
string_class s1("hello");
string_class s2("goodbye");
```

If the internal representation of the string_class string is a c string, what happens to memory allocation when you swap the values? For example, let's say string_class allocates `char* c_str_s1 = new char[5]`, but `char* c_str_s2 = new char[10]` (because, say, after 5 the size doubles). If we do something like `std::swap(c_str_s1, c_str_s2)`, is the memory allocated for each c string swapped, or is minimum allocation given to each?

Comment: why swap pointer have anything to do with memory allocation? in this case, both are deleted with `delete[] ptr`

Comment: `swap` doesn't throw, which means it doesn't allocate. Anything beyond that is implementation-defined. If you want to know exactly what your implementation does, look at the source (probably in some header file) or watch it with a debugger.

Comment: A "C string" is not a type but a convention how to use a `char*`. For sure, `std::string` doesn't conform to this convention, as it can well contain null-bytes.

Comment: You should use `std::string` not define your own `string_class` which your question does not detail.

Comment: Just a nit-pick... to be a "C string", "hello" needs to be stored in ASCIIZ with a traililng NUL ala "hello\0", so you'd need `new char[6]` not `5`....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pointers are swapped as-they-are: that means each of them after the swap will point to the memory allocated for the other. The contents of memory are not supposed to be changed in any other way.

Answer (score 2):

When you swap `std::string`s, they internally exchange fields including `char*` pointers, no allocation is performed.

**EDIT** I missed the point that you are not using `std::string`s, but you should consider doing it anyway.

Comment: You mean `std::string`-s, not "strings"

Comment: I don't think the question is about `std::strings`.